# iOS - Custom keyboard doesn't show up sometimes, how to fix?

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard

Im' dealing with some really stupid errors.
One of them is the keyboard doesn't showing without reasons.
Its so annoying.

I've read this article here http://beta-blog.archagon.net/2014/11/08/the-trials-and-tribulations-of-writing-a-3rd-party-ios-keyboard/ and i give the empathy with the author.

But i need solution to work around to bring better experience to the users.
Anyone have solution for it?

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue in the Simulator or on devices as well?

Comment: @DannyBravo On the device. Especially in the spotlight search. Everytimes the keyboard doesnt show up, i have to open spotlight 3 times to get the keyboard show up again.

Comment: I think it is simply impossible to solve at this point :( It happens with every single 3rd party keyboard I have tried, and you'd think the big ones should be getting it right. It's certainly a bug on Apple's side.

Comment: @David Are you sure? Because i'm testing with some 3rd party keyboards, and some i didn't see it happen. Swiftkey, Fleksy? or i don't use them long enough. My customer complains about this annoying bug a lot and i've been searching solution for 4 months :(

Comment: It @TomSawyer it's not consistently reproducible, but I've experienced this behaviour with every keyboard I've tried - including SwiftKey (which I am using most of the time), Fleksy, Swype and NinType.

Comment: @TomSawyer There are many Custom Keyboards they won't appear for Spotlight. If you are testing use Notes, Contact, or Photos search etc to make it work.

Comment: @iphonic well, i've tested Swype, Swiftkey and don't see it happen. Even i've tested this keyboard https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard for a while i don't see it happen too. I've visited Swype website and they said this error has been fixed since iOS 8.1 http://www.swype.com/product-features/ios/known-issues.html , are you guys still experience this error in iOS 9.3.2?

Comment: In order to fix that problem, did you guys managed to profile your keyboards  using Instruments? (I tried and failed)